# Object turns white when rendering/render Layer Colors disappear

Tags: cycles-render-engine, render-layers

[image]Help, where is the color?! I tried everything going through material etc. Im barely learning on youtube with blenderguru but I don't know why my objects colors disappeared when rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a material in the render layer's settings, it will override all other materials at the time of rendering.

[image]

To clear it press on the **X** to the right of the material.

Once cleared, the render layer will use the materials set for each of the objects in the scene.

**EDIT:**

Newer versions of blender don't use layers, but "collections" so the override function is in the scene>View Layer section.

[image]

Additional info:

[Where is the Layers panel in Blender 2.8?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96463/where-is-the-layers-panel-in-blender-2-8/96465#96465)

[2.8 - Is it possible to assign (override) a material to a whole collection?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136678/2-8-is-it-possible-to-assign-override-a-material-to-a-whole-collection)