# Materials Disappear in Render

Tags: rendering, materials

EDIT: Here's the project file:

[image]

I followed Blender Guru's tutorial for making an animated flag, and everything seemed like it was working fine. I even walked away from the render last night seeing each frame rendering with all the materials intact.

I wake up to this:

[image]

In 3D view, when I go to rendered shading mode, it looks correct:

[image]

But if I actually render it, the materials disappear:

[image]

Why is this??

I used the Import Images as Planes add-on for the flag texture, so I'm under the impression from the tutorial that UV mapping is not necessary, but anyway, the regular glossy textures of the metal flagpole and Suzanne head are also disappearing.

I googled and searched, but this doesn't seem to be the same as any problem I've seen anyone else post about. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90551/object-turns-white-when-rendering-render-layer-colors-disappear/90554#90554

Comment: No, I found a post where that was the solution, but there's no material sitting there in mine. Thanks!

Comment: If you found a solution please write an answer to your own question. It might help other users who run into a similar situation. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Not a solution - that other question didn't apply to me. Still have the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Which specific button did you press to render?

Comment: I pressed Animation and used png as the output, because I'm outputting frames to then edit in the Video Sequence Editor. First time I've done that, but I'm trying to follow what the Blender manual says is best practice as well as mostly what I'm learning from the Blender Guru videos.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. We don't know how you set up your project or your textures or render settings. Consider sharing your .blend file (with the images used as textures [packed into the file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/82965/1853)) so that others can inspect it. You can upload it at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then paste the resulting link as part of your question.

Comment: My guess is this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/came-back-to-a-blender-file-now-not-rendering/5286#5286

Comment: @RayMairlot Okay, now the render is working! But that still doesn't explain why all my rendered frames from last night are missing the materials. That's very strange.

Comment: @RayMairlot But yesterday, when I rendered the frames for the animation, I had nothing in the sequencer, and yet all the rendered frames from last night are missing materials. Are you saying that previously rendered png files can be changed based on what you do in Blender after that?

Comment: Did you press the render button **in the menu**, or **at the bottom of the 3D View**? They do different things.

Comment: Well, I rendered again after disabling Sequence in Render Settings > Post processing, and it worked. But this still doesn't explain why it didn't work properly last night.