# Objects gray when rendered

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

I cant seem to figure out coloring through this tutorial I'm using https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1-iKFazCaeQ
I follow what this person does and mine stays gray.

[image: rendered just gray]

Anyone got any tips or a better way to do this?

Comment: Is your material assigned to any faces?

Comment: Make sure that you did not set a material in the layer settings. Read: [Object turns white when rendering/render Layer Colors disappear](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90551/object-turns-white-when-rendering-render-layer-colors-disappear/90554#90554)

Comment: looks there are no light in the scene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you have two materials on that object. I'm guessing the second material (the one you edited to have some color) is not assigned to the mesh anywhere.

In edit mode select the whole object <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>. Now click on the material in the list (yours is called "Material.002") and press the *Assign* button.
[image: Assign material button]

---

Now if you are not using the first material for anything you can simply remove it. Go to Object mode (you can not remove material slots in edit mode), with the first material selected click on the minus button on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you unwrap the material onto the object by selecting all the faces in edit mode and clicking U then unwrap. If the material goes on warped then you can either project from view or by marking seams.

Comment: look at his nodes, he does not have any image in the material. Thus UV unwrapping does not matter.